# How to change element in xaml that are in visual tree

Tags: wpf

I'm new to WPF and tyring to uderstand the best way I can modify any given control attributes.  What I was trying to achieve is to show tooltip for a cell. Yes a quick google and can see xaml of how to do it. But I want to understand how can one learn to figure out this out using some tool.
I came across Snoop that can show visual tree of a control very easily (CTRL+SHIFT Mouse over). What I'm trying to understand is if one knows of visual tree, how can one change it? For example, let's say I use WPF DataGrid and bind it to a source and display column using DataGridTextColumn.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}">
```

Now let's say I want to show tooltip for each cell. So I fire up Snoop and CTRL+SHIFT mouse over the cell. Snoop shows me that its a DataGridCell that is using Border and withing it ContentPresenter which ends up using TextBlock to show the value. So that means that if I can somehow access that textblock, I can set its tooltip property using binding. Issue is that I don't know how I can access it in xaml.

In other words, knowing a visual tree, how can one access it in xaml for any given control. This will also be very handly for 3rd party controls.

Thanks

Comment: your question is too abstract....can you put it in a more concrete way?

Answer (score 0):

Your'e asking quite a bit here, and i'm not sure I completely understand your intention, so I hope I got this right. Your'e asking if you can access the complete visual representation of each control and change it using xaml. The answer to that is yes, but you shouldn't.

I'll get to what I mean in a bit, but first I'd like to clarify some concepts, since i'm not sure you're using them correctly.

- **XAML:**
  Xaml is the declarative markup representation of your views and nothing more. Xaml syntax directly corresponds to it's respective [classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#object_element_syntax) and their [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788723%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#property_element_syntax). Xaml maps tags to classes and attributes to properties. It's a small distinction, but it's important to think this way. Everything you can do in xaml you can also do in code (although it would often be much more work). Again: xaml refers to markup code only.

---

```
<ClassA PropertyA="Value">
  <ClassA.PropertyB>
    <ClassB />
  </ClassA.PropertyB>
  Default property value
</ClassA>
```

---

- **Logical tree**:
  The [logical tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#logical_tree) is the runtime representation of your xaml code. it consists (mostly) of the controls you set in your xaml files.
- **Visual tree:**
  The [visual tree](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21495/Understanding-the-Visual-Tree-and-Logical-Tree-in) is the visual representation the logical tree. It contains much more since it contains the concrete visual representation of everything displayed in your view. Most of the logical tree can't be directly displayed. WPF uses [Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Control Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jitghosh/archive/2007/12/27/wpf-control-templates-an-overview.aspx) together with [Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine exactly how each object is supposed to look. In case of data templates that can also mean simple data objects and not only WPF controls.

Now for your question: *so can you access the concrete visual representation of each control?*
**Yes**, but you'll have to use control templates to manipulate it's visuals. Also, control templates are usually applied to control types and not specific controls, so you'll have to deal with that as well.

And that's why you **shouldn't** access it. The xaml representation usually gives you all you need to modify your control, and even if you do use templates you shouldn't change every last piece of it. Templates are used to style a control, so only write enough to show it as you wish. There's no need specify everything.

*However* you can access the entire visual tree more easily using procedural code, if you use the [VisualTreeHelper class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (that's how snoop does it, by the way). Using it you can traverse the visual tree and access all it's classes and members. If you really want to access every single visual object you'll do it much more easily with the VisualTreeHelper.